# Trouble using setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I've never been able to properly use the setTimeout function, so I tried writing a sample script to update a progress bar, but again, it does not work.  Instead, the entire program runs before the progress bar is updated to 100%.  Would somebody be able to look at this code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The code I'm trying to use is from http://digitalbush.com/projects/progress-bar-plugin/

Thanks!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/jqueryprogressbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Progress Bar test</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    /* progress bar container */
    #progressbar{
        border:1px solid black;
        width:200px;
        height:20px;
        position:relative;
        color:black; 
    }
    /* color bar */
    #progressbar div.progress{
        position:absolute;
        width:0;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color:#369;
    }
    /* text on bar */
    #progressbar div.progress .text{
        position:absolute;
        text-align:center;
        color:white;
    }
    /* text off bar */
    #progressbar div.text{
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>

<div id="progressbar"></div>
<input type='button' value='start' onClick='run()' />

<script>
function run() {
    for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
        setTimeout( function() {
            $("#progressbar").reportprogress(i);
        }, 500);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what sort of behavior you expect.  How do you know how long it should take for the progressbar to complete?  In other words, why is a timeout an appropriate way to show the progress bar in the first place?

Comment: Well, in this example I was trying to get it to slowly increase from 0 to 100% in say about 10 seconds.  Instead, it jumps from 0 to 100% without anything inbetween.  Ultimately, I want to implement this in code that involves lots of processing and for loops, to let the user know how far along it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that variable `i` becomes the part of the closure and, when the function is executed, is already equal to `100`.

The code you have currently literally creates a hundred of timeouts referencing the same variable(global i). By the time all of the functions are executed, i equals 100, therefore you report 100 as current progress 100 times.

The proper version should look like that:

```
function run() {
    var i = 0;
    setTimeout( function updateProgress() {
        $("#progressbar").reportprogress(i++);
        if (i < 100){
            setTimeout(updateProgress, 500);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

You could check [closures](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures) part of javascript garden for explanation and possible other solutions.

Comment: Yeah, this does what I wanted.  I guess I have a better understanding now of how exactly setTimeout works.  I just need to remember that the rest of the script will continue to run before the setTimeout delay triggers.  Now I'll see if I can transfer this over to larger program.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` is not `sleep` (JavaScript doesn't have a `sleep`).

As you loop round, you set the function to run in 500ms, then you **immediately** set it to run again in 500ms, and so on. So effectively, you set it to run 100 times in 500ms, and have set `i` to 100 before the first time it executes (since it takes a JS engine less then half a second to run that for loop 100 times).

You want something more like this:

```
var interval, i = 0;
interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (i === 100) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        $("#progressbar").reportprogress(i);
        i++;
    }
}, 500);
```