# setting a timer in JS for 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set a timer in my js code...

```
$("header").addClass("scrolled");

//INSERT TIMER FOR ONE SECOND HERE

 var newHeaderHeight = $("header").outerHeight();
 $('#mainContent').css('padding-top', newHeaderHeight);
```

I have tried a few things but no joy.eg:

```
$.doTimeout(1000, function () {
                });
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble using setTimeout function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679096/trouble-using-settimeout-function)

Answer (score 1):

Use the JavaScript function setTimeout(function, milliseconds, optional stuff) to do this:

```
$("header").addClass("scrolled");

setTimeout(function () {
    // This will be executed after 1,000 milliseconds
    var newHeaderHeight = $("header").outerHeight();
    $('#mainContent').css('padding-top', newHeaderHeight);
}, 1000);
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/hygnow06/